# Esp8266, Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp8266

написал tcp сервер для одного клиента под esp8266, а как сделать чтобы можно было подклюючиться нескольким клиентам? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

На одном порту, например, 80-м, принимаете запросы на подключение. При запросе выбираете любой свободный порт и говорите клиенту подключаться к нему.